# How to upload Twitch panel extension in Twitch extension store?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitch

I recently created a twitch panel extension and I have no idea how to upload it and make it available for install. I have seen Twitch extension documentation and I did not find how to upload the extension. If anyone knows how to do it, please share your knowledge.

This is documents I have seen https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/extensions

right now i am stuck here and have no idea where to next from here
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A Twitch Extension comprises of HTML/JS/CSS and any background images.

So you'd need to create a zip file that contains your front end assets. In this case that would appear to be the contents of extensions-hello-world/public

Also that looks like a REALLY old Version of the developer rig. You may need to manually update https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/extensions/rig as on older version broke it's auto update mechanism

Assets and the full control time line for a extensions is at https://dev.twitch.tv/console/extensions

A similar question was asked and answered on the Dev Forums: https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/solved-404-the-specified-key-does-not-exist/11921/2

The salient point for the post describes how to select and zip you files. Select all the files in the folder and zip from there. Don't right click and zip the folder itself.

[image]